# Could not load file or assembly ServiceStack.OrmLite after uninstall

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

After accidentally installing ServiceStack into my project with this command:
`Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71`

Which simply caused a "Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.OrmLite, Version=3.9.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8b49dc47f4701f66' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I promptly turned around and uninstalled it with this command: 
`Uninstall-Package ServiceStack` and still I get the above error.

When I search the entire project after the uninstall, I still find tons of references to ServiceStack, so... Manually deleting the ServiceStack.Client.dll, ServiceStack.Common.dll, ServiceStack.Text.dll and all associated files as well as the Packages.xml still results in the above error.

Searching for "ServiceStack" after doing the above returns no matches and, yet, the error persists.

Any and all clues desperately appreciated, as my entire website is now dead and no longer usable...

Comment: Do you use source control? If you do (which you should) you can just revert back to a version prior to installing it...

Comment: This particular project is not in source control. It will be, but not just yet. That said, I do have backups and restoring from one of those does solve the problem, but I lose work as a result. And I'd still like to find the answer to this problem...

Comment: Ironically, this problem is back. I recreated the entire solution. It consists of the Main site, a Forum in a sub-directory, and a Wiki installed as a child application. After recreating everything, and then copying the wiki after a rebuild of that wiki, the problem has re-emerged without me doing anything beyond the above.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this turned out not to be what I thought it was. The real problem was being created by a child application using .NET 2.0 under a parent application with .NET 4.0. The child app was trying to load DLLs needed by the 4.0 app, including ServiceStack. Modifying the web config with instructions not to inherit those DLLs fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can force an uninstall of ServiceStack with:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package ServiceStack -Force
```

Other instructions on installing/uninstalling and updating ServiceStack v3 are on the [v3 wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3).

Comment: Thanks, but no joy... It tells me it "can't find the ServiceStack package" and then still fails with the same error when I compile or try to run.

Comment: @EDanaII than force uninstall the packages you do still have installed.

Comment: Does deleting the entire Packages.xml file count as an uninstall? That's what I did initially, and the problem still persists.